# How to make caption field required in media library?

Tags: forms, media, library

[image: Caption field]

Hi, my question is easy. I don't know how to make the caption's textarea required for user.
Is it possible to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See if either of these plugins helps you do that: [Custom Field Template](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-template/) or [Mandatory Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mandatory-fields/).

If not, it might require changes to a theme's functions.php. Hopefully, you don't have to change anything in the core WordPress files - that can be quite risky.